# NodeJS/GeddyJS: setting limit on fetching data from model

Tags: node.js, geddy

I'm using GeddyJS framework for a NodeJS application.

I got stuck with a problem in setting limit while making a call to **all()** method in any model.

I tried providing **limit** as one of the option but its not working as expected.

**geddy.model.User.all({userId: 1}, {sort:{createdAt: "desc"},limit:10}, function(err,data){**

Any Help???

PS: We are using MongoDB as database.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for I think:

```
geddy.model.User.all(
  {}, 
  {sort: {createdAt: 'desc'}, limit: 10},
  function (err, data) {
    // do stuff
  }
);
```

If this isn't working for you, let us (the framework devs) know what error your getting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in the docs about using limit; however, this might work for you.

```
geddy.model.User.all(
                     {userId: 1}, 
                     {sort:{createdAt: "desc"}},
                     {limit:10}, 
                     function(err, data){
                      // do stuff
                     })
```